# Typescript type intersection in type alias

Tags: typescript

Here is the example from official document in [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) section.

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> };

interface Person {
    name: string;
}

var people: LinkedList<Person>;
var s = people.name;
//var s = people.next.name;
//var s = people.next.next.name;
//var s = people.next.next.next.name;
```

when I try this example it generates the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

people is a linkList type. How to correctly fill the people link list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign it a value, just declaring type is not enough. For example:

```
var people: LinkedList<Person> = {name: "Alf", next: {name: "Tim", next: null}};
```